# Specify endpoints of lines by percentage of image size

Tags: imagemagick, nine-patch, imagemagick-convert

I'm trying to draw the stretch bars on various sizes of ninepatch images.  I'm doing this in a script, and I'd like to be able to specify a different master image or scale it to a different size without manually recalculating all the pixel coordinates of the lines I'm drawing on it.  Is there a way to specify the endpoints of lines as a percentage of the image size?  I tried this, which does not work:

```
convert -draw 'line 0,45% 0,55%' $myfile tmp~ && mv tmp~ $myfile
```

I had hoped this would draw a line along the middle 10% of the left side of the image.  It does draw a line, but it ignores the percents and draws the line from 0,45 to 0,55 regardless of the image size.

If this is not possible with ImageMagick, is there another Linux command-line tool I could use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can do that using percentages, but you can get it pretty succinct and avoid having to do any calculations using `bash` or `bc` or somesuch by using ImageMagick's built-in `fx` operator to calculate the line position as a function of the image height.

The best I can come up with is this:

```
linespec=$(convert image.jpg -format "0,%[fx:int(h*0.45)],0,%[fx:int(h*0.55)]" info:)
convert image.jpg -stroke red -strokewidth 32 -draw "line $linespec" image.jpg
```

Of course you can replace `image.jpg` with a variable, and you can also make it an (ugly) one-liner by putting the first command in the middle of the second if you really want to.

Note also, that there is no need to create a temporary image and rename like you do - you can just draw on your original like I have.

Comment: Awesome.  I had starred this question that seemed vaguely similar to mine... maybe you can help this guy out, too.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21876433/imagemagick-calculate-perspective-without-knowing-image-dimensions?rq=1

Comment: No problem - I think I have a solution sorted for him too :-)