# How I Can Composite image with imagemagick with this file?

Tags: imagemagick, perspective

When i want to composite one image with png file i use:

```
exec("convert  1.png  ".$newfile1."  -geometry +110+70 -compose DstOver -composite   ".$result_image);
```

And when i want use Perspective i use :

```
exec('convert '.$newfile1.' -matte -background transparent -virtual-pixel background -distort Perspective "0,0 0,0 393,0 236,65 393,486 393,486 0,486 153,486" '.$newfile1.'');
```

But with this png file for example :

[image]

create Perspective file is very different and hard because i don't know the source image size and how create best perspective..

any help?
(soryy for my bad english)

Comment: Maybe have a look at, and vote for :-) my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21876433/imagemagick-calculate-perspective-without-knowing-image-dimensions/25894182#25894182

Comment: I think i explain to bad, i need to best solution for perspective , i think i need use viewport ??